# Inventory reindex runs catalog price reindex also

Tags: magento2, price, reindex, inventory, magento2.3.1

Magento version: 2.3.1

When I run inventory reindex from command line it first runs inventory reindex and then price reindex after that.

Here is the command I executed:

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex inventory
```

Output on console:

```
Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:40
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:08:10
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:25:01
```

As you can see from console output, price and catalog search reindex also executed.

How can I prevent running price reindex automatically? I want just inventory reindex.

Comment: How do you run indexes? What commands? What sequence?

Comment: @DominicXigen updated the command and output in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you are look for, but this might be helpful.

As [Eugene](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/277304/9169) mentioned, to keep the data consistency price indexing is bound to inventory indexing.

Have a look at below code in the file `vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/etc/mview.xml`.

```
 <view id="catalog_product_price" class="Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Price" group="indexer">
        <subscriptions>
            <table name="cataloginventory_stock_item" entity_column="product_id" />
        </subscriptions>
    </view>
```

What this materialized view code does is, it adds a trigger to `cataloginventory_stock_item` table.

If your inventory indexing is configured to 'Update by Schedule' and when there is a change in product inventory in `cataloginventory_stock_item` table, it makes entry for product in table `catalog_product_price_cl`.

When price indexing runs, `catalog_product_price_cl` table is used to identify the product ids for which price indexing needs to run.

If you want to disable entry in `catalog_product_price_cl` table during inventory indexing, you need to override this file and comment the code and run setup:upgrade. It will remove the trigger from `cataloginventory_stock_item` table. Of course you need to verify that there isn't any data inconsistency after this modification.

Answer (score 3):

Described behavior may seem to be completely unobvious, however it's expected.

The thing is, that indexers may depend on each other, like in your case, `Catalog Search` indexer depends on `Price` indexer, which, in turn depends on `Inventory` index. This chain might not be optimal, however all of them must run to ensure data consistency, as inventory availability may impact data in the price index and so on.

Indexer dependencies are configured via DI configuration, and I believe it's possible to override this config for your specific case. However, this is not something I would recommend, as it may impact data consistency and correct display of catalog information.

Looking at the initial question I assume that you are concerned about performance. Have you looked into reindex on save or reindexing at a time when store does not experience biggest customer flows? This kind of problem may be mitigated in different ways depending on your business scenario. Please let us know the details and might find a solution together.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to first runs inventory reindex and then price reindex after that.

You have to need run below command for individual selected indexer run.

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex cataloginventory_stock
>
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_price

Comment: I have updated command and output in the question. Let me know if you can help.

Comment: Yes let me know what is the issue after run above command step by step.

Comment: Issue is, I'm running command to reindex only inventory but if you see the console output, its reindexing price and catalog search as well. I dont want price and catalog search to run after inventoy reindex.

Comment: If you run cmd: php bin/magento indexer:reindex cataloginventory_stock
then only execute Stock index.

Comment: I tried that. It does not reindex price but Catalog Search reindex is still happening.
Here is the output:

`bin/magento indexer:reindex cataloginventory_stock`

`Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01`